# Xamarin Forms - xUnit setup not working as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms, installation, task, moq, xunit

In my login viewmodel I inject a navigationservice.That navigation service is used in the following code to navigate to a particular screen

```
    public async Task HandleLoginCommand()
    {
        var asdf = _navigationService.PushAsync(new MainPage(), false);

        await asdf;
    }
```

The interface I am mocking

```
   public interface INavigationService
   {
       Task PushModalAsync(Page contentPageToOpen, bool animated);
       Task PushAsync(Page contentPageToOpen, bool animated);
   }
```

I wrote a unit test for this and it looks like:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task HandleLoginCommand_NavigatesToMainPage_WhenLoginSucceededAsync()
    {
        // Arrange
        navigationService.Setup(s => s.PushAsync(It.IsAny<Page>(), false)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

        // Act
        // _loginViewModel.LoginHandelerCommand.Execute(null);
        await _loginViewModel.HandleLoginCommand();

        // Assert
        navigationService.Verify(m => m.PushAsync(It.IsAny<Page>(), false), Times.Once);
    }
```

This doesn't work, the setup isn't overriding the behaviour of the pushasync method. When I try catch it, it says:"You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.". So I guess the setup goes wrong, but why?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the setup. You are trying to run UI code in a non UI context. Pages require Xamarin.Forms.Init(); to be invoked prior to using it, which happens at run time.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a solution. I have been searching for a day.. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: And where am I running UI code preciesely? Because in my code I say: If PushAsync is called, dont really call it but just return Completedtask, it is mocked right so there is no UI code involved?

Comment: `new MainPage()` is UI code. That is what is causing the error

Comment: I see, is there a way I can still unit test this? Or is unit testing thos method not possible?

Comment: Have you tried just calling the said function before invoking member under test?

Comment: Calling the function normally by just running the app works, only when testing it doesnt work

Comment: I understand that. When testing in isolation, not all parts are activated like when running normally, so that means that sometimes you have to call certain functions yourself to mimic run time features.

Comment: I tought that the setup method was used for this.. specify the method, give it parameters and exptected value etc.. and when it's triggered, it should behave like specified. Am I saying something wrong here?

Comment: You are confusing some of the context. Yes the mock will behave as expected when setup. but the problem is not the mock setup, it is the actual code you are trying to test. Like I said at the start your code is invoking code that expected to be invoked on the UI at run time.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I have googled a little bit and it's true. Do you perhaps know if there are ways to test the things I want to test?